# How to multi-paragraph quote within quote?

Tags: quotes, dialogue

When a speaker's words in dialogue extend to more than one paragraph, we use an opening quotation mark at the beginning of each paragraph and use a closing quotation mark only at the end of the person's speech, not at the end of every paragraph. **But what if it's quote within quote?** Which of the following examples is correct, example 1 or 2?

**Example 1:**

My friend said:

"Jonah prayed to God from the belly of the fish, saying:

"'For you cast me into the deep,
into the heart of the seas.

"'The waters closed in over me to take my life;
the deep surrounded me.

"'Weeds were wrapped about my head
at the roots of the mountains.

"'When my life was fainting away,
I remembered the Lord,
and my prayer came to you.
Salvation belongs to the Lord!'

"And the Lord spoke to the fish, and it vomited Jonah out upon the dry land."

**Example 2:**

My friend said:

"Jonah prayed to God from the belly of the fish, saying:

'For you cast me into the deep,
into the heart of the seas.

'The waters closed in over me to take my life;
the deep surrounded me.

'Weeds were wrapped about my head
at the roots of the mountains.

'When my life was fainting away,
I remembered the Lord,
and my prayer came to you.
Salvation belongs to the Lord!'

"And the Lord spoke to the fish, and it vomited Jonah out upon the dry land."

Comment: Triple quotes are new to me. I'd rather see indenting to align the elements together for the reader.

Comment: Alternatives to multi-paragraph block quoting would be to (1) reformat so it's one paragraph (2) rewrite so you don't have a quote within a quote, e.g. *My friend quoted Jonah: "..."* (3) do away with the inner quotes and trust the audience knows it's a quotation (4) use italics (5) use slashes to indicate line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to make things as clear as possible for your reader. I find example #2 potentially confusing, because upon reaching the last line and seeing an opening double quotation mark, a reader might not remember that the previous lines were also part of the quotation with double marks. I'd therefore prefer example #1 over #2.

[*CMOS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style) provides similar guidance:

> If the quoted passage contains an interior quotation that also runs for more than one paragraph, a single quotation mark is used at the interior quotation's beginning, before each new paragraph (**inside the double quotation mark**), and at its conclusion. (*CMOS* 14th ed. section 10.29; bold formatting mine)

That being said, I think that [block quotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_quotation) would work better (as suggested in a comment above). You can then simply use formatting (such as extra indentation or smaller type) to distinguish inner quotations from outer ones.